# Simulink: Get Path of Blocks Higher on the Hierarchy

Tags: matlab, path, simulink

In `Matlab`, the `get_param` and `set_param` commands require the exact directory of a block.
The `gcb` command can give you the path of a currently selected block.
What is the best method to determine blocks paths relative to this block?

*For example*, relative path identifiers sometimes use periods.

To find the current path, use `'./'`.
To find the parent path, use `'../'`.
To find the parent of the parent, use `'../../'`.

These do not function in conjunction with `gcb` however.

### MWE

In `Simulink`, if I create a block and select it,
and then type into the `Matlab` window:

`get_param([gcb], 'ObjectParameters')`

I am provided with a list of block parameters,
any of which may be altered using `set_param([gcb], <parameter>, <value>)`.

Included in the list of parameters is `Parent`, which provides the parent path.
Is there a command which can take a path and remove until the next `'/'`?
(Or more usefully, a command which acts as a reverse `fullfile`?)
(Someone mentioned regular expressions, so I'm looking into those.)

Also, (less important to me, but for posterity),
is there a command which can find children paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_param(<blockname>, 'Parent')` for parent of the current block. To get parent of parent and higher layers you need to create your own function like this:

```
function blk = getParent(blk, n)
for k=1:n
    blk = get_param(blk, 'Parent');
end
end
```

So `getParent(gcb, 1)` gives you the parent, `getParent(gcb, 2)` gives you the parent of the parent and so on.

To find the children you should use [`find_system`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) together with `SearchDepth` argument.

```
find_system(gcb) % All children regardless of depth

find_system(gcb, 'SearchDepth', 1) % Immediate children

find_system(gcb, 'SearchDepth', 2) % Immediate children and their children
```

Note that if some of the children are library links you need to use `FollowLinks` option as well.